# JSON request with Twitter oEmbed

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I'm trying to use the Twitter API to embed a tweet on my site - and doing the JSON call using jQuery. The Twitter reference page is pretty vague about how to actually do the Get request: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-oembed.html

I'm missing something basic. Why does:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FInterior%2Fstatus%2F507185938620219395', 
    function(data) { alert("hi");}
  );
});
```

not result in my alert?

Comment: what is this URL `https://publish.twitter.com/oembed`..the doc says `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status`

Comment: See the example at the bottom of the page. If you copy and paste my URL into your browser, you download a JSON file.

Comment: can you try this...
`var href = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(' I check it out here @XXX') + '&url=' + encodeURIComponent(\websiteURL\);
    jQuery("\your element\").attr("href", href);` on click on this anchor tag, a pop up will come and you can share it